# How to check if at least one element of a list is included in a list column?

Tags: list, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, exists

Some mock data:

```py
test_data = [('1', '[tech, fx]'),
             ('2', '[industry, computer]'),
             ('3', '[5G, Apple]')]
test_data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(test_data).toDF(['id', 'text'])
```

I wan't to create a new column that indicates if the words ['fx', 'computer'] can be found in the column called 'text':

Desired output:

```py
result = [('1', '[tech, fx]', '1'),
          ('2', '[industry, computer]', '1'),
          ('3', '[5G, Apple]', '0')]
result = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(result).toDF(['id', 'text', 'indicator'])
```

Comment: User [`array_intersect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array intersect`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

test_data.withColumn(
    "indicator",
    f.when(
        f.size(f.array_intersect(f.col("text"), f.array(f.lit("fx"), f.lit("computer")))) > 0,1
    ).otherwise(
        f.when(f.col("headline").startswith("Tonight"), 1).otherwise(0)
    )
).show()

+---+--------------------+-------------+---------+
| id|                text|     headline|indicator|
+---+--------------------+-------------+---------+
|  1|          [tech, fx]|  Todays Tags|        1|
|  2|[industry, computer]|  Weekly Tags|        1|
|  3|         [5G, Apple]|      General|        0|
|  4|         [5G, Apple]|Tonights News|        1|
+---+--------------------+-------------+---------+
```

This would also mean you have the `text` column as `ArrayType`.
*OP also wanted to check if `headline` starts with `Tonight`.*

Comment: @SinaF yes that is also possible updated the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using higher-order function [`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.exists.html#pyspark.sql.functions.exists)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

arr_col = F.split(F.expr("TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM text)"), ", ?")
bln_col = F.exists(arr_col, lambda x: x.isin(['fx', 'computer']))
result = test_data.withColumn('indicator', bln_col.cast('int'))

result.show()
# +---+--------------------+---------+
# | id|                text|indicator|
# +---+--------------------+---------+
# |  1|          [tech, fx]|        1|
# |  2|[industry, computer]|        1|
# |  3|         [5G, Apple]|        0|
# +---+--------------------+---------+
```

Since your "text" column was in string format, the `arr_col` expression transforms it to an array first. You need an array, as `exists` only accepts array type columns.

`trim` removes the symbols `[]` from both ends of the string. `split` splits on the delimiter which is a regex pattern `, ?`, which means that it splits on every comma `,` which could (or could not) be followed by one space.

Comment: @SinaF of course, but this is a separate question. You should post different questions as different questions. The following would give you boolean output which now you know how to transform to integer. `F.col('headline').startswith('Tonight')`

Comment: my real column is : ('tags', 'array<string>')

Comment: That's because in your example you provided a string data type, and your original data is of array data type...

Comment: Don't use the `arr_col` expression. That expression made array from the string in your example. You already have an array, so you don't need the first line. Start from the 2nd row, but change the `arr_col` with your column name.